# Perform an action when a wireless keyboard is connected

Tags: linux, keyboard, devices, bluetooth

I need to perform a command when I connect a bluetooth keyboard. How can I 'listen' this event?

Answer (score 8):

When a piece of hardware is plugged in, the [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) framework decides what to do with it. A typical action is to create a device node under `/dev`, but you can run any shell command.

First, you need to figure out how to identify your device. Connect the keyboard and run `udevadm info -a -n /dev/input/event9` where the last argument is the path to the device file in `/dev/` corresponding to your device. You can omit the `/dev/` prefix. You can use a syspath (a path under `/sys`) instead of a device node name by replacing `-n …` by `-p class/input/event9`. In all cases, replace `input/event9` by the appropriate path for your device. This prints various characteristics of your device. Collect one or more of the lines of the form `SETTING=="VALUE"`, enough to identify your device uniquely.

Create a file under `/etc/udev/rules.d` called `vemv-keyboard.rules` or some such. Put a line in this file with the settings to be matched and an action to run. Take care to use the proper operators: it's `==` for properties to be matched, `=` for properties to be set, and `+=` to specify additional actions. Something like:

```
# Run a program when my wireless keyboard is connected
SUBSYSTEMS=="input", ATTRS{vendor}=="Yoyodene", ATTRS{model}=="Bluetooth keyboard 9000", RUN+="/path/to/script $root/$name"
```

The program will run the next time you plug the device in (adding the file has no effect on already-connected devices). You check that your rule would have the desired effect by running `udevadm test class/input/event9` (where the argument is the syspath as above). If you want to apply the rule manually, run `udevadm trigger --sysname=class/input/event9`.

Comment: While your answer looks excellent I've had no luck getting it to work :( here are my inputs/outputs: https://gist.github.com/vemv/5275029

Comment: @vemv You need to use the absolute path of the script. I can't see why `ATTRS{name}=="Apple Wireless Keyboard", RUN+="/home/vemv/bin/myscript"` didn't work though.

Comment: All the files listed when running `udevadm test class/input/event9` start with two digits. Could that have something to do?

Comment: @vemv No, that's not a problem, and the output from `udevadm test` shows that your rules were read. The rules files are read in lexicographic order, the ones that begin with a digit are read before the ones that begin with a letter.

Comment: Can you try to just RUN+="/path/to/a/script" without any arguments and see if you can get udev to actually run a script of yours? It shouldn't make any difference, but I recall having a hard time to make my rules work. I ended up doing some logic in my script, which udev could have done just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like running `udevadm monitor` is a good basis for solving my problem. One can have a daemon parsing its output, filtering the desired entries, and reacting to those events.

Comment: There is such a daemon. It's called udevd. You configure it with "rules", which are stored in `/etc/udev/`. It comes with a man page too.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Sounds like your pointer is going to save me a lot of work :)